# Jrating and php, display rate in div with dynamic id

Tags: php, jquery, html

Thank you everyone for such support. I've learned a lot from the seniors here. I'm quite new to jquery and php.

Recently i try to add jrating for items list generated by php from Mysql. Item list is displaying with rating stars. I can alert the current rate on each item. But when i try to add a message in item list and try to display the div id in alert it gives me the very first id of div. Although i checked on browser and div ids different. Div ids are generated by php. My question is how can i alert the current div id in jrating?

Please help me, I'm posting the script below and message div.

Please please help me or at least give me a hint what I'm doing wrong.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".basic").jRating({
            onClick : function(element,rate) {
                //alert(rate);
                var rate_text = $('.rate_text').attr('id');
                //$('#'+rate_text).html(rate);
                alert(rate_text);
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

message div is as follows:

```
<div class="rate_text" data-id="rate_text<?php echo $r["id"]?>"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

`attr('id')` will load the element's `id` tag.

You probably want to have the `data('id')`:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".basic").jRating({
        onClick : function(element,rate) {
            //alert(rate);
            var rate_text = $('.rate_text').data('id');
            //$('#'+rate_text).html(rate);
            alert(rate_text);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: data('id') not working. attr(data-id) is working but again it gives the first id for every item. If 5 items are there i can see through browser that every div has seperate ids. for example rate_text57, rate_text62, but it always gives rate_text57 the first item id for every item. I'm stuck